# Using AJAX to "post" a logged in user's user-name onto a mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, html5-canvas

I am currently working on an HTML5 canvas/JavaScript game. I wish to save the logged in users Score which i have done, but i want their name to be placed in the database as well. On my Index.php page i have :

```
echo 'Hello ' . $_SESSION['user_name']
```

In my java script file:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "savescore.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {
    name: "user_name",
    score: score
  },
  success: function() {
    console.log("Finished uploading score");
  }
});
```

This saves the score, but not the user_name, I was wondering how I would go about placing the player's username inside the name:. Is there anyway to get the $_SESSION inside the JavaScript? And then use it inside the $.ajax function? Any answers or even advice on a different approach is much appreciated.

Comment: if the value you want is stored in session then why do you need to send it trough post? just retrieve it in your savescore function

Comment: I should of thought of that before haha. Thank you for the suggestion, iv spent time on it but can't figure the right code. $name = $_POST["$_SESSION['user_name'];"] doesn't work, $_SESSION['user_name'] = $name 
$name = $_POST['$name'] doesn't seem to either. Any suggestions?

Comment: should be `$name = $_SESSION['user_name'];` just make sure to call `session_start()` at the beginning of the file `savescore.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed **`js`** with **`PHP`**. Also write `session_start()` at top of script as well to use `$_SESSION`.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "savescore.php",
   type: "post",
   data: {
       name: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>,
       score: score
   },
   success: function() {
       console.log("Finished uploading score");
   }
});
```

Comment: All of my javascript isn't embedded into the php file, it's just linked with <script src="game.js"> </script>, as there is a lot of code. Can I still embed PHP into JavaScript?

Comment: @user2582299 Yeah rename that file from `.js` to `.php`. and include it like `<script src="game.php"> </script>`